# pandas returning empty DataFrames for CSV

Tags: csv, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some large csv and xlsx files which I need to set up pandas DataFrames for. I have code which locates these files within the directory (when printed, these show correct pathnames). These paths are then passed to a helper function which is meant to set up the required DataFrames for the files, then the data will be passed to other functions for some manipulation. I intend to have the data written to a file (by loading a template, writing the data to it, and saving this file) once this is completed.

I currently have code like:

```
import pandas
# some set-up functions (which work; verified using print statements)

def createDataFrame(filename):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(filename), skip_blank_lines=True, index_col=False,
                             encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)
```

When I try `print(df)`, I get:

> Empty DataFrame
>
> Columns: [a.csv]
>
> Index: []

and `print(StringIO(filename))` gives me:

> <_io.StringIO object at 0x004D1990>

However, when I leave out the `StringIO()` around `filename` in the function, I get this error:

> OSError: File b'a.csv' does not exist

Everywhere that I've been able to find information on this has either just said [import and start using](http://synesthesiam.com/posts/an-introduction-to-pandas.html), or talks about using `read_csv()` rather than `from_csv()` ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103624/load-csv-to-pandas-multiindex-dataframe), which wasn't very helpful here), and even [the current pandas docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/10min.html) basically say that it should be as easy as passing the file to `pandas.read_csv()`.

1) I've checked that I have full permissions and that the file is valid and exists. Why am I getting the OSError?

2) When I use `StringIO()`, why am I still getting an empty DataFrame here? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need `StringIO`? won't it just work without this? i.e. `pandas.read_csv(filename,.....)`

Comment: As posted in my question, without StringIO I am getting an OSError. I have been unable to discover why, and would appreciate any pointers that could solve that issue (and then maybe it will all work)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this.

StringIO was the root cause of this problem. Because I'm on Windows, `os.path.is_file()` was returning False, and I got the error:

> OSError: File b'a.csv' does not exist

It wasn't until I stumbled upon [this page from the Python 2.5 docs](http://pydoc.org/2.5.1/ntpath.html) that I discovered that the call should actually be `os.path.isfile()` on Windows because it uses **ntpath** behind the scenes. This is to better handle the difference in pathnames between systems (Windows uses '\', Unix uses '/').

Because I had something weird going on in my paths, pandas was unable to properly load the CSV files into DataFrames.

By simply changing my code from this:

```
import pandas
# some set-up functions (which work; verified using print statements)

def createDataFrame(filename):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(filename), skip_blank_lines=True, index_col=False,
                             encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)
```

to this:

```
import pandas
# some set-up functions (which have been updated)

def createDataFrame(filename):
    basepath = config.complete_datasets_dir
    fullpath = os.path.join(basepath, filename)

    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pandas.read_csv(fullpath, skip_blank_lines=True, index_col=False,
                             encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)
```

and appropriately updating the function which calls that function:

```
def somefunc():
    dfs = []
    data_lists = getInputFiles() # checks data directory for files containing info
    for item in data_lists:
        tdata = createDataFrames(item)
        dfs.append(tdata)
    print(dfs)
```

I was able to get the output I was looking for:

```
[    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
1  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
2  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40,     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
1  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30]
```

which is a list of two DataFrames, the first of which came from a CSV containing only the numbers 1-40 (on 4 rows total, no headers); the second file contains only the numbers 1-30 (formatted the same way).

I hope this helps someone in the future.