# pandas read in MultiIndex data from csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiIndex csv file which I would like to read in.

The data is saved in the csv file as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfcsv = pd.read_csv("/FilePath/MultiIndex_Example.csv")
dfcsv
```

Which essentially leads to a data frame below:

[image]

**Python Dataframe construction below:** *(easy reconstruction)*

```
d = {'Country': ['City', 'PostCode','Day1','Day2','Day3'], 'UK': ['London', '123',47,42,40],'USA': ['New York', '456',31,22,58]}
dfstd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

> However, when I read in the data I need the 1st column to act as the
>   multiIndex. Essentially creating a data frame as below:

```
arrays = [['UK','USA'],['London','New York'],['123','456']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Country', 'City','Postcode'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 2), index=['Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3'], columns=index)
df.columns
```

[image]

**I was wondering if there is a simple way of achieving this via pd.read_csv or a pd.MultIndex construction ?**

*FYI I tried the below but couldn't get it working*
[Load CSV to Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103624/load-csv-to-pandas-multiindex-dataframe)

Comment: just use headers as [0,1]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the following is what you need:

```
dfcsv = pd.read_csv("/FilePath/MultiIndex_Example.csv", index_col=[0], header=[0,1,2])
```

Here, `index_col` will take your first column which is `0` as index and header as 1st and 2nd row as header's which are `0,1,2` as its *0-indexed*

Comment: Ah this nearly works, if you add header=[0,1,2] then it works perfectly!

Comment: @RK1 - Sorry, I think 3 row is data, answer was edited.