# Rearranging Index, Rows and Columns from Pandas-DataReader

Tags: python, pandas

I´m pretty new to this,
Im looking to get Data for multiple Stocks and getting them sorted by Symbol and Name (Ticker). When I run my code I get all the Data I want but its sorted in all kinda ways but not the way I want it to be.

I´ve tried to rename Columns and Index but I always get an Multiindex error.

```
import datetime as dt 
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader.data as web 

# Variables of Tickers and Start and End dates of which Data is gathered
tickers = ["MSFT", "AAPL", "TSLA"]

# Where to get data from 
start = dt.datetime(2016, 1, 1)

df = web.DataReader(tickers, "yahoo", start)

#Writes Data into Excel
df.to_excel("Allstockdata.xlsx") 

print(df)
```

I get the following :

```
Attributes-|High----------|Low-----------|---Open----|Close|Volume|Adj Close|------------------------------
Symbol-----|MSFT|AAPL|TSLA|MSFT|AAPL|TSLA|-M-|-A-|-T-|M|A|T|M|A|T-|M|A|T|----------------------
Date-------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-01-04-|-54-|-105|231-|53--|102-|219-|54|102-|230|
```

I hope you get the idea of what I´m getting.

What I want looks more like this:

```
Date------------|Ticker--|Open--| High-| Low | Close | Volume | Adj Close |-------------------------------------
2016-01-04--| MFST---|---54--|54-----|53----|54-----|53778000|50--------------------------------------------
2016-01-04--| AAPL---|--102--|105---|102--|105----|67649400|98-----------------------------------------------
2016-01-04--| TSLA---|--220--|231---|219--|223----|9874225 |223--------
```

Sorry for the ugly way to show the problems I have, I hope anyone is still willing to help a newbie out.

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
import datetime as dt 
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader.data as web 

# Variables of Tickers and Start and End dates of which Data is gathered
tickers = ["MSFT", "AAPL", "TSLA"]

# Where to get data from 
start = dt.datetime(2016, 1, 1)

# d = {"Date":[1, 2, 8], "Ticker":[2, 3, 4], "Open":[5, 6, 7], "High":[8, 9, 0] }
d = {"Date":[""], "Ticker":[""], "Open":[""], "High": [""], "Low":[""], "Close":[""], "Volume":[""], "Adj Close":[""]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1

# df = web.DataReader(tickers, "yahoo", start)

df1.to_excel("Allstockdata.xlsx",columns=["Date", "Ticker", "Open", "High", "Low", "Volume", "Adj Close"]) #Writes Data into Excel
```

UPDATE:

```
import datetime as dt 
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader.data as web 

# Variables of Tickers and Start and End dates of which Data is gathered
tickers = ["MSFT", "AAPL", "TSLA"]

# Where to get data from 
start = dt.datetime(2016, 1, 1)

df = web.DataReader(tickers, "yahoo", start)
d = {"Date":[""], "Ticker":[""], "Open":[""], "High": [""], "Low":[""], "Close":[""], "Volume":[""], "Adj Close":[""]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


print(df.head())
# df.to_excel("Allstockdata.xlsx")
# df1.to_excel("Allstockdata.xlsx",columns=["Date", "Ticker", "Open", "High", "Low", "Volume", "Adj Close"]) #Writes Data into Excel
```

UPDATE WHAT I GET AS COLUMNS:

MultiIndex([(     'Date',     ''),
            (     'High', 'AKTX'),
            (     'High', 'ARCI'),
            (     'High', 'CETX'),
            (      'Low', 'AKTX'),
            (      'Low', 'ARCI'),
            (      'Low', 'CETX'),
            (     'Open', 'AKTX'),
            (     'Open', 'ARCI'),
            (     'Open', 'CETX'),
            (    'Close', 'AKTX'),
            (    'Close', 'ARCI'),
            (    'Close', 'CETX'),
            (   'Volume', 'AKTX'),
            (   'Volume', 'ARCI'),
            (   'Volume', 'CETX'),
            ('Adj Close', 'AKTX'),
            ('Adj Close', 'ARCI'),
            ('Adj Close', 'CETX')],
           names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])

Comment: We are here to help you Feyi :), but you need to make your question clear, so we can read and understand it. Plz add the code that you tried, as code block ( select code and CTRL+K )

Comment: Try to specify the columns when you export to excel : df.to_excel("Allstockdata.xlsx",columns=['col 1', 'col 2'] )

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and sorry for the bad description. I tried your approach but received this error:  KeyError: 'passes columns are not ALL present dataframe'

Comment: did you replace col1, col2 with existing columns that you already have?

Comment: check an example below.

Comment: I tried it that way and I was able to arrange the Colums but now it doesnt put in any of the data that I was trying to get. I will try to post my code below

Comment: Instead of a new answer, edit your question and add an "Updated" section. It is empty because "d" is empty. You need to read your data from d = web.DataReader(tickers, "yahoo", start)

Comment: it´s still either empty but with nice columns or its full of data but in a random order. Head´s almost exploding lol thannks for your patience

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I run it I get: "KeyError: "Date"" . When i only print(df.columns()) right after I get the df=web.DataReader(tickers, "yahoo", start) I get: TypeError: "MultiIndex" object is not callable. So maybe I dont even have any identified columns in the data somehow even tho i can see them in excel..

Comment: Try this to find the columns: print(df.columns), then use the names of the columns as I did before, again start with one column only

Comment: i updated. entering the output i have when running print(df.columns) I think the issue might be that Symbols is listed as names. Thanks for your patience with me

Comment: So, the data is multi-index. I updated my answer below. You need to read more about multi indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Specify columns names when export to excel :

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2':[1, 4, 9, 16]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1

df1.to_excel("test.xlsx",columns=['col2', 'col1'] )
```

In your case, and after you updated the code, you should use the correct data frame :

After you get the df from the web :

```
df = web.DataReader(tickers, "yahoo", start)
```

Try to pass each column to the new df :

```
d = {"Date":df['Date'], "Ticker":df['Ticker'],...
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Or directly :

```
df.to_excel("Allstockdata.xlsx",columns=["Date"])
```

Try one column first, "Date" column and if works, then add more. Be careful, if df doesn't contain the exact column name, it will return an error.

**Multi index data** :

```
df.to_excel("Allstockdata.xlsx",index_col=[0,1])
```

References below. The first reference below is very useful for your case.

- [Load CSV to Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103624/load-csv-to-pandas-multiindex-dataframe)
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html